# Is it safe to call ReadAsString and then ReadAsStream on an HttpClient response Content?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

On .NET Core, using a `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`, is it safe to first call `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`, and then call `response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()`?
For example, do something like this.

```
var response = await client.GetAsync("http://example.com");

var respStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
// ... Do something with the string

var respStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
// ... Do something with the stream
```

I'm worried about the response content being streamed so that it's not possible to read it twice.

I have tested it with a couple of requests, and it always works for me, but is it guaranteed to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is safe as long as content is not disposed.

If you look how those methods are implemented in [HttpContent](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpContent.cs) class (`response.Content` returns the instance), you will see that memory buffer is used internally.

```
public Task<string> ReadAsStringAsync()
{
    CheckDisposed();
    return WaitAndReturnAsync(LoadIntoBufferAsync(), this, s => s.ReadBufferedContentAsString());
}
```

and

```
public Task<Stream> ReadAsStreamAsync()
{
    CheckDisposed();

    ArraySegment<byte> buffer;
    if (_contentReadStream == null && TryGetBuffer(out buffer))
    {
        _contentReadStream = Task.FromResult<Stream>(new MemoryStream(buffer.Array, buffer.Offset, buffer.Count, writable: false));
    }


    if (_contentReadStream != null)
    {
        return _contentReadStream;
    }


    _contentReadStream = CreateContentReadStreamAsync();
    return _contentReadStream;
}
```